# Create an installable WordPress plugin in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, wordpress

I'm very new to WordPress and I have a requirement where I'm stuck. As of now my website is in WordPress ( frontend + backend ) but for one feature I need to use laravel.
Is it possible to create an installable plugin in laravel for wordpress and use it just for one feature?

Comment: I didn't understand your question completely, but you can read this http://blog.jgrossi.com/2014/working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together/

Comment: Is it possible to create a plugin in laravel and then use it in wordpress like any other available plugin ?

Comment: You can create plugin for WordPress, your functionality may be developed using any framework, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have wrong concept on what is what? Worpdress is basically procedural CMS made in php while laravel is framework. So basically two are different things but same platform php 
A CMS (Content Magagement System) is used to manage content on a website. It usually provides tools to make this task as easy as possible.

Examples of CMSes: Drupal, Joomla, DotNetNuke,wordpress etc.

A framework is like a set of libraries / classes to build a web application. Many frameworks provide libraries for database access, templating engines etc. This way, you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

A CMS is often build upon a Framework.

Examples of frameworks: CodeIgniter, Laravel,CakePHP, Kohana...

The question you are asking is just like  asking if we could make an app in windows and run in android,mac etc ?